# Displaying an array from within a file

Tags: c++, mingw

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<fstream.h>
using namespace std;
ifstream f("nr.txt");
int n=0,i=1,aux[100],j=1,m,v[100];
int main()
{     
    while(f>>v[i])
    {
        i++;
    }
    n=i;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        cout<<v[i]<<" ";
}
```

my "nr.txt" file contains the following numbers :-3 -10 0 7 -5 7 51 -800 6 3798
when I run the program it should display all those numbers from the file, but it displays one more ( 0 )...why is this? if I declare the array inside the main function it displays 6226116 instead of that 0.

Comment: Array indices start at 0.

Comment: no,no they don't...string indices start at 0

Comment: Yes they do... Read any C++ tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So `i` starts at 1, which means that if there is only one number, the while cycle runs once, setting `i` to 2, and then `n` is set to `i` which becomes also 2. When you print the numbers you go from 1 to `n` (inclusive), which is 1 and 2, but you only have one number in the array.

In short, you're printing one more element than you should.